# Proper way to get the base path when including an image from a module?

Tags: uri, i18n-l10n

When using just [drupal_get_path()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_get_path/7) to include an image from a module directory, this produces non-existent urls when using language prefixes.

I've seen a couple of modules prepend [base_path()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/base_path/7) to deal with this, but on the api page for base_path() someone comments that you should use the `DRUPAL_ROOT` constant. What is the recommended way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Drupal core uses [`file_create_url()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!file.inc/function/file_create_url/7) for internal images like this (eg, the default favicon.ico handling in includes/theme.inc).

This ensures that [`hook_file_url_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_file_url_alter/7) gets called (the [CDN](https://drupal.org/project/CDN) module does this), that the basepath gets set, and that everything is escaped properly.

So, I would use

```
$path = drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodle');
$url = file_create_url($path . '/images/some.jpg');
```

Comment: Worth noting, `file_create_url` is used by [`theme_image`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme_image/7)

Comment: Yeah, and @DavidThomas's answer is most appropriate if you want an actual <img> element.

Answer (score 4):

You could use

[`theme_image`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme_image/7)

e.g:

```
  $variables = array(
    'path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'my_module').'/images/image.jpg', 
    'alt' => 'My image',
    'title' => 'My image title',
    'attributes' => array('class' => array('my-image')),
  );
  $img = theme('image', $variables);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use [$base_url](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!globals.php/global/base_url/7) with [drupal_get_path()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_get_path/7).

```
global $base_url;
$img_path = $base_url . '/' . drupal_get_path('module', 'YOUR_MODULE') . '/images/your_image.png';
```

In this way the image path won't be affected by i18n site url prefix settings.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [System stream wrapper](https://drupal.org/project/system_stream_wrapper) module. It gives you a module://, theme:// and profile:// stream wrapper. These wrappers will (probably) be part of D8 core.

Answer (score 0):

Sometime you may need to pass a NULL langage in the url function.

Example from commerce_paypal

Not working link (original code)

```
  return url(drupal_get_path('module', 'commerce_paypal_ec') . '/images/paypal-ec-logo.gif', array('absolute' => TRUE));
```

Working link (hacked code)

```
  return url(drupal_get_path('module', 'commerce_paypal_ec') . '/images/paypal-ec-logo.gif', array('absolute' => TRUE, 'language' => ""  ));
```

Note: Hacking contributed modules is never reccomanded, of course.